# What is paragraph TE000128012 OR what is \u switch for TOC in MS word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I am reading a web page about the codes for TOC in MS word [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-TOC-Table-of-Contents-field-1f538bc4-60e6-4854-9f64-67754d78d05c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).
It explains the possible switches when creating a TOC, one of them being `\u`.

> \u
>
> Builds a table of contents by using the applied paragraph TE000128012.

What do they mean by "paragraph TE000128012" ?

a google search gave only three results, none of them were helpful :D

Thank you !

Comment: Just a guess: possibly someone has reported an error in the documentation, Microsoft has assigned a code (TE000128012) to that report, inserted the code as a placeholder, and in this case did not get around to replacing the placeholder by some updated text.

Comment: Well, I [asked](https://twitter.com/bsivanov/status/1019195597243473922), and the code was eventually removed from the page. Apparently it was a bug in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> \u:   Builds a table of contents by using the applied paragraph outline level (outline level: Paragraph formatting you can use to assign a hierarchical level (Level 1 through Level 9) to paragraphs in your document. For example, after you assign outline levels, you can work with the document in outline view or in the Document Map.).

From [here](http://phlogtastic.blogspot.com/2010/05/word-toc-switches.html?_sm_au_=iVVD74q1LNLV13W2)

Comment: Thank you! any idea what is the mysterious "paragraph TE000128012" ?

Answer (score 1):

Create some test document, and type in it:

```
foo

bar

bar

foo
```

Next, put the caret on the 1st foo line, and change it's outline level from "Body text" to "Level 1", as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Repeat this action for 2nd foo line.

The same way, change the outline level of bar lines from "Body text" to "Level 2".

After these actions, you can use `{toc \u}` to build a table of contents.

From my point of view, the `\u` switch intended for use with custom heading styles (if you want to use something like "My Heading 1" and "My Heading 2" instead of build-in "Heading 1" and "Heading 2" and then create TOC based on these custom styles).

But, you also can create TOC based on your custom styles using the `\t` switch.

That's mean, `\u` and `\t` do very similar job. `\u` is more automated, while `\t` gives you ability for more precise "tuning".